# First item in queue plays when different item is selected

Tags: ios, swift

I've been having trouble with the Media Player Framework and UICollectionView.

It all starts by invoking my function `setPlayerQueue(with storeIds: [String], start index: Int)` (see below) from the `didSelectItemAt` UICollectionViewDelegate method. This is expected to enqueue the store ids in an order that matches the display of tracks in the UICollectionView. So if cell 15 is tapped, track 15 should play. What actually happens is that track 1 plays first, and if I tap again, then track 15 will play as expected.

When I tap a cell in my UICollectionView, a queue is created using an array of store ids via the [`func setQueue(with descriptor: MPMusicPlayerQueueDescriptor)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmusicplayercontroller/2582423-setqueue). I also assign the MPMusicPlayerQueueDescriptor `startItemID` property to the store id associated with the selected index path before invoking `setQueue(descriptor)`.

```swift
func setPlayerQueue(with storeIds: [String], start index: Int) {

  let descriptor: MPMusicPlayerStoreQueueDescriptor = MPMusicPlayerStoreQueueDescriptor(storeIDs: storeIds)

  descriptor.startItemID = storeIds[index]

  player.setQueue(with: descriptor) // player: MPMusicPlayerController.applicationMusicPlayer
}
```

Reproduce:

1. Create array of store ids (e.g. 20 tracks)
2. Scroll to bottom of UICollectionView (e.g. 20 items)
3. Call `setPlayerQueue(with: storeIds, start: indexPath.item)` by selecting any cell (e.g. index 17)
4. Call `prepareToPlay() { e: Error? in }`, followed by `play()` in its closure

I expect track 17 to play, but track 1 plays instead. If I tap the same cell 17 again, track 17 will play as expected.

I have scoured the internet and docs, but to no avail. Any help will be appreciated.

I have filed a [bug report](http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=6073460426014720) with Apple just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else deals with the same problem, I have found a workaround and have some insights to share.

#### Workaround

In your selector method for the `MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChange` notification, add some logic to compare the current item with the expected item. If the items do not match, set the queue again.

Example code:

```swift
...

// Register observer for MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChange
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, 
                                       selector: #selector(self.playbackItemDidChange), 
                                       name: .MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChange, 
                                       object: player)

...

// Your selector method
@objc func playbackItemDidChange(_ sender: NSNotification) {

 // Store identifier of item currently playing
 let nowPlayingItem = player.nowPlayingItem // unwrap optional
 let currentItemStoreId = nowPlayingItem.playbackStoreId 

 // Store identifier of item that should play first
 // `descriptor` is an MPMusicPlayerStoreQueueDescriptor object
 let expectedItemId = self.descriptor.startItemId

 // Compare
 if currentItemStoreId != expectedItemId {

  // An `MPModelObjectMediaItem` appears first and its store id is empty.
  // I'm ignoring the MPModelObjectMediaItem here
  if (currentItemStoreId != "") {

     // The wrong item is playing.
     // Set your queue once again and playback should commence from the correct item.

  }

 }

}
```

Notes:

- Make sure you invoke `stop()` on your player before re-setting the queue.
- You will need additional logic to allow items to be manually changed (e.g "skip" and "back" actions), as the workaround will prevent these actions.

#### Observations

I originally suspected there was an issue with UICollectionView because the bug only appear when I scrolled. However, I have observed that the problem actually linked to the queue size. When my queue had around 10 items, any item I tapped first played as expected. When I had 20 items, and I tapped item 17, item 1 would play instead. If I tapped item 17 a second time, it would then play as expected.

This is most likely a bug. Apple hasn't responded to me yet, but in the meantime, my workaround does the trick.